# Issue while copying text using TextBoxWatermarkExtender

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have some text-boxes and using AJAX TextBoxWatermarkExtender to watermark it.My problem is if i am copying the value of text-box to another using jquery the watermark text is copying.I want proper text,that is empty string.How can i achieve this?

```
$('#textbox2').val( $('#textbox1').val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare value of textbox with your water mark if it is same as your watermark then take value as `""`(blank) other wise take `$('#textbox1').val()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `TextboxWatermarkExtender` control creates a behavior object on the client side that exposes the method you're looking for.

You can query the behavior object from the `BehaviorID` property you have set on the extender (it defaults to its `ClientID` IIRC), using the [$find()](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Global/FindShortcutMethod.aspx) function:

```
$("#textbox2").val($find("yourTextBox1BehaviorID").get_Text());
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBoxWatermark is an ASP.NET AJAX extender that can be attached to an ASP.NET TextBox control to get "watermark" behavior - [Ref](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

So here you need to compare the watermark text as well i.e.

```
if($('#textbox2').val() != 'watermark text'){
 $('#textbox2').val( $('#textbox1').val() );
}
```

If there is only watermark text present and you want to copy it, you can check it same as above and put the empty value in second textbox

```
if($('#textbox2').val() == 'watermark text'){
     $('#textbox2').val('');
}
else{
   $('#textbox2').val( $('#textbox1').val() );
}
```

Comment: This is normal thing.Is there any other common way to find it is water mark text

Comment: You can go with the answer posted by @Frederic :)